# Prove $\int_0^\pi\sin^{2n}t dt$ without using Residue Theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

How may one prove something similar as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561433/using-contour-integrals-to-calculate-other-integrals?lq=1) but from $0$ to $\pi$ and without using the Residue Theorem?

I was told to consider the contour integral
$$\int_{|z|=1}(z-\frac{1}{z})^{2n}dz/z
$$

and so I parametrise it with $z=e^{it} $ 
and got $$\int_0^\pi\sin^{2n}t dt=\frac{1}{4^{n}i^{2n+1}}\int_{|z|=1}(z-\frac{1}{z})^{2n}dz/z$$
I am not sure what I did is helpful, even if so I have no idea how to continue from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be to use the binomial theorem for $(z-1/z)^{2n}$, and then for each $ -n \leq  k \leq n$ calculate, if you don't know it yet
$$\int_{|z|=1} z^kdz$$

You can also calculate $\int_0^\pi\sin^{2n}t dt$ without complex Analysis. Use integration by parts with $f =\sin^{n-1}(t)$ and $g'=\sin(t)$, and then use $\cos^2(t)=1-\sin^2(t)$. This gives you a relation between  $\int_0^\pi\sin^{2n}t dt$ and $\int_0^\pi\sin^{2n-2}t dt$, and then by induction you can prove the formula you seek.

**Added**

$$(z-1/z)^{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} z^{2n-k}(-1)^k z^{-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} z^{2n-2k}(-1)^k $$

Therefore 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} z^{2n-k}(-1)^k z^{-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k}(-1)^k \int_{|z|=1} z^{2n-2k-1} dz$$

Now, just calculate $\int_{|z|=1} z^{2n-2k-1}$ you will see that this is zero for all $k \neq n$.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on how to use the binomial theorem?

Comment: @SilverBlack added