# Relationship between Laplace transform and Bessel function

Tags: laplace-transform, bessel-functions

How to show $L^{-1}(\frac{1}{s^2-1})= J_{0}(t)$

I have deduced that,

$L^{-1}(\frac{1}{s^2-1}) = sinht$
How $sinht$ is related to $J_{0}(t)$. Kindly help

Comment: That's a bit weird, I thought that:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}\right)=J_0(t)$$
You have correctly deduced that $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s^2-1}\right)=\sinh(t)$.

Comment: how to show $L^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt(s^2+1)})=J_{0}(t)$. kindly show proof

Comment: See for instance: [Laplace transform of Bessel function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667639/laplace-transform-of-bessel-function?rq=1)