# Evaluate $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (1+e^{2i\phi})^{\alpha} (1+e^{-2i\phi})^{\beta} \, \mathrm{d}\phi$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, special-functions

I should evaluate:

$$ \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (1+e^{2i\phi})^{\alpha} (1+e^{-2i\phi})^{\beta} \, \mathrm{d}\phi $$

by using the binomial theorem and the identity:

$${}_2F_1 \left(\begin{array}{c}a , b \\ c \end{array};x\right) = \frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c-b)} \int_{0}^{1} t^{b-1}(1-t)^{c-b-1}(1-xt)^{-a} \, \mathrm{d}t$$

So first using binomial theorem I get:

\begin{align*}
&\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sum_{k=0}^{\alpha} \binom{\alpha}{k} e^{2i\phi k} \sum_{k=0}^{\beta} \binom{\beta}{k} e^{-2i\phi k} \, \mathrm{d}\phi \\
&= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sum_{k=0}^{\alpha} \sum_{l=0}^{\beta} \binom{\alpha}{k} e^{2i\phi k} \binom{\beta}{l} e^{-2i\phi l} \, \mathrm{d}\phi \\
&= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sum_{k=0}^{\alpha} \sum_{l=0}^{\beta}  \binom{\alpha}{k} \binom{\beta}{l} e^{2i\phi(k-l)} \, \mathrm{d}\phi
\end{align*}

But from here I don't know how to proceed or rather how to use the identity. Any hints?

Comment: What are your $\alpha$ and $\beta$? If they are non-negative integers, then this can be computed fairly in a straightforward way as illustrated in J.G.'s answer. Otherwise, we can still represent the integral using a hypergeometric function.

Comment: Good question. It is not specified in the exercise :/ just that it should be solved by the identity. I would assume any integer

Comment: @SangchulLee do you know how to evaluate it over the hypergeometric identity?

Comment: @craft J.G.'s answer can be generalized, and no hypergeometric formula is needed. Indeed, by Euler formula and parity, $I=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (2e^{ix}\cos(x))^a (2e^{-ix}\cos{x})^bdx=2^{a+b-1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{a+b}x \cos((a-b)x) dx$. 
[Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456899) that
$f(v,a)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \cos ^{v-1}(x) \cos (a x) \, dx=\frac{\pi }{2^v v B\left(\frac{1}{2} (a+v+1),\frac{1}{2} (-a+v+1)\right)}$, let $v\to a+b+1,a\to a-b$ one obtain $I=\frac{\pi \Gamma(a+b+1)}{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}$.

Comment: Nevertheless, the formula featuring $f(v,a)$ can be established via hypergeometric means rather than contour integration as linked, that is, to expand the $\cos(ax)$ in terms of $\sum_k {a_k} \cos(x)^k$ (see for instance G&R), and use Beta identity & Gauss $_2F_1$ formula.

Comment: Thanks @Iridescent, I've updated to acknowledge this.

Comment: @Iridescent, That is interesting. This shows that $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{k}\binom{\beta}{k}=\binom{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha,\beta}$$ holds even for non-integer $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: @Iridescent thanks, can you maybe elaborate on the hypergeometric solution or give me a reference? (what is G&R?)

Comment: @craft $1$. G&R denotes Gradshteyn & Ryzhik's *Table of integrals, series and products*. $2$. See also G&R for expansion of $\cos(ax)$. You may easily find the hypergeometric solution then.

Comment: Thanks! Will do!

Comment: @SangchulLee Indeed, $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } z^k \binom{a}{k} \binom{b}{k}=\, _2F_1(-a,-b;1;z)$ holds. Thus by Gauss formula one have $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \binom{a}{k} \binom{b}{k}=\frac{\Gamma (a+b+1)}{\Gamma (a+1) \Gamma (b+1)}$.

Comment: One may easily generalize this to higher weights, say a $_3F_2$ example $$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}^2 \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k}=\frac{\pi ^2+\sqrt{2} \left(3 \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{8}\right)^2 \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^2+\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^2 \Gamma \left(\frac{9}{8}\right)^2\right)}{\pi ^3}$$ One may refer to arXiv $2010.03727$ for more Gamma evaluation of hypergeometric series.

Comment: Cant find a representation for cos ax in G&R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\beta$ is a non-negative integer, with $z=e^{2i\phi}$ this becomes$$\oint_{|z|=1}(1+z)^{\alpha+\beta}\frac{dz}{2iz^{\beta+1}}=\pi[z^\beta](1+z)^{\alpha+\beta}=\pi\binom{\alpha+\beta}{\beta}=\frac{\pi\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)\Gamma(\beta+1)}.$$Update: @Iridescent has pointed out how we can generalize to complex $\beta$. The integral is $2^{\alpha+\beta-1}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{\alpha+\beta}\phi\cos[(\alpha-\beta)\phi]d\phi$, since the integrand's imaginary part integrates to $0$ on $[-\tfrac{\pi}{2},\,\tfrac{\pi}{2}]$. [An old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456899) proves this is indeed $\tfrac{\pi\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)\Gamma(\beta+1)}$.