# Compute the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^a (x) \sin (a x) \ dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

> I need to evaluate the following integral $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^a (x) \sin (a x) \ dx,\ \ ~\ \  a\geq 0$$

I tried the following :$$I(a):=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^a (x) \sin (a x) \ dx$$
$$I(a)=\Im\left(\int_{0}^{\pi/2}  \left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\right)^a e^{i a x} \ dx\right) $$
$$I(a)=\Im\left(2^{-a}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}  \left(1+e^{-2ix}\right)^a e^{2i a x} \ dx\right) $$
$$I(a)=\Im\left(2^{-a}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}  \left(1+e^{-2ix}\right)^a e^{i (2a+2) x} \ \frac{i}{2}d(e^{-2 i x})\right) $$
$u=e^{-2ix}$ ($u$ travels clockwise along the unit circle from $1$ to $-i$ to $-1$ then Cauchy's theorem lets us deform the countour to just under the real axis from $1$ to $0$ to $-1$)  $$I(a)=\Im\left(2^{-a-1}\  i \int_{1}^{-1}  (1+u)^a u^{-a-1} \ du\right) $$
$$I(a)=\Im\left(2^{-a-1}\  i \int_{1}^{0}  (1+u)^a u^{-a-1} \ du\right)+\Im\left(2^{-a-1}\  i \int_{0}^{-1}  (1+u)^a u^{-a-1} \ du\right) $$
$$I(a)=J(a)+K(a) $$ where $$J(a)=\Im\left(2^{-a-1}\  i \int_{1}^{0}  (1+u)^a u^{-a-1} \ du\right) $$ and $$K(a)=\Im\left(2^{-a-1}\  i \int_{0}^{-1}  (1+u)^a u^{-a-1} \ du\right)$$
$$J(a)=-2^{-a-1}\int_{0}^{1}  (1+u)^a u^{-a-1} \ du $$ In $K(a)$, substitute $u=-v$ so that $du=-dv$ $$K(a)=\Im\left(-2^{-a-1}\  i \int_{0}^{1}  (1-v)^a (-v)^{-a-1} \ dv\right)$$
$$K(a)=\Im\left((-1)^{-a}\  i \ 2^{-a-1} \int_{0}^{1}  (1-v)^a v^{-a-1} \ dv\right)$$
Write $-1=e^{-i\pi}$ and $i=e^{i\pi/2}$
$$K(a)=\Im\left(e^{i\pi (a+1/2)} \ 2^{-a-1} \int_{0}^{1}  (1-v)^a v^{-a-1} \ dv\right)$$
$$K(a)=\sin(\pi (a+1/2)) \ 2^{-a-1} \int_{0}^{1}  (1-v)^a v^{-a-1} \ dv$$
$$K(a)=\cos(\pi a) \ 2^{-a-1} \int_{0}^{1}  (1-v)^a v^{-a-1} \ dv$$
So by the definition of Beta function $$K(a)=\cos(\pi a) \ 2^{-a-1} \Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(-a)$$
By reflection formula of Gamma function $$K(a)=-\cos(\pi a) \ 2^{-a-1} \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi a}$$

Comment: Suppose $a>0$ and not be an integer, your $K(a)$ converges, but your $J(a)$ diverges. Your result is incorrect.

Comment: @MathFail Thanks for pointing this out. Can you write an answer which I can accept?

Comment: Yes, I have written an answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Also asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3419834).

Comment: @metamorphy But in the link the limits of integration are from $0$ to $\pi$, whereas in this question the limites are from $0$ to $\pi/2$

Comment: The core symmetry is different, in your link, the core part is $\sin^{a} x$, which is the essential part leading to the beta function. In this OP, the core part is $\cos^{a} x$, which  leads to the eq.(2) $$I=\frac1{2^{a+1}}\int_0^1\frac{(1+t)^a-(1-t)^a}{t}~dt$$, where both parts diverge and cancel each other. If shift the integrand in your link by $\pi/2$, you will get the same core $\cos^{a} x$, but the integral limit becomes $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ and the odd part in $e^{ibx}$ (which is $\sin bx$) vanish and you go back to $\cos^{a} x\cos (bx)$ case, which is still the even symmetry. @metamorphy

Comment: @MathFail: *Looks like the **end** of my answer there is the **only** visible thing ;)*

Comment: I saw your $F_+$ and $F_-$, their combination will give the result in my eq.(2). Eq.(2) can be further written as $$\text{P.V} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{(1-t)^a}t~dt$$ but there is no fundamental progress.  I believe there is no way to further simplify them with complete gamma or beta function. So I stay with the series form :) @metamorphy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^a (x) \sin (a x) \ dx=\Im\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^a (x) e^{ia x}~dx,\ \ \ \  a\geq 0$$

Let $z=e^{ix}$, and $I=\Im K$, where

$$K=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^a (x) e^{ia x}~dx=\frac1{2^a i}\int_{C_1}\left(\frac{1+z^2}{z}\right)^a\cdot\frac{z^a}{z}~dz$$

Define $$f(z)=\left(\frac{1+z^2}{z}\right)^a\cdot z^a$$

We use the following contour:

[image]

take the branch cut as shown in the figure.

$$\arg(z-i)\in (-\pi,\pi],~~~\arg(z)\in (-\pi,\pi],~~~\arg(z+i)\in (-\pi,\pi]$$

therefore,

$$\begin{align}\arg f&=a\left[\arg(z+i)+\arg(z-i)-\arg(z)\right]+a\arg(z)=a\left[\arg(z+i)+\arg(z-i)\right]\end{align}$$

we have

$$\frac1{2^a i}\int_{C_1}\frac{f(z)}z~dz+\frac1{2^a i}\int_{C_2}\frac{f(z)}z~dz+\cdots+\frac1{2^a i}\int_{C_5}\frac{f(z)}z~dz=0$$

The integral vanishes on $C_2$. On $C_4$, we have

$$\frac1{2^a i}\int_{C_4}\frac{f(z)}z~dz=\frac1{2^a i}\cdot \frac{-2\pi i}4 Res(z=0)=-\frac{\pi}{2^{a+1}}$$
On $C_3$, we have $\arg f=0+0=0$, $z=r e^{i\frac\pi2}$

$$\frac1{2^a i}\int_{C_3}\frac{f(z)}z~dz=\frac1{2^a i}\int_1^0\frac{(1-r^2)^a}{r}~dr=\frac i{2^a}\int_0^1\frac{(1-r^2)^a}{r}~dr$$

[image]
On $C_5$, we have $\arg f=\beta+(-\beta)=0$, $z=r e^{i\cdot0}$

$$\frac1{2^a i}\int_{C_5}\frac{f(z)}z~dz=\frac1{2^a i}\int_0^1\frac{(1+r^2)^a}{r}~dr=-\frac i{2^a}\int_0^1\frac{(1+r^2)^a}{r}~dr$$

Therefore,

$$K+0+\frac i{2^a}\int_0^1\frac{(1-r^2)^a}{r}~dr-\frac{\pi}{2^{a+1}}-\frac i{2^a}\int_0^1\frac{(1+r^2)^a}{r}~dr=0\tag{1}$$
and

$$I=\Im K=\frac1{2^a}\int_0^1\frac{(1+r^2)^a}{r}~dr-\frac1{2^a}\int_0^1\frac{(1-r^2)^a}{r}~dr$$

Let $t=r^2$

$$I=\frac1{2^{a+1}}\int_0^1\frac{(1+t)^a-(1-t)^a}{t}~dt\tag{2}$$

Use binomial series expansion,
$$I=\frac1{2^{a+1}}\int_0^1\frac1t\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom ak t^k-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom ak (-1)^kt^k\right)~dt$$

Even terms cancel out, we get

$$\begin{align}I&=\frac1{2^{a+1}}\int_0^1 \frac1t\cdot2\sum_{m=0}^\infty\binom{a}{2m+1} t^{2m+1}~dt=\frac1{2^{a}}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\binom{a}{2m+1}\int_0^1  t^{2m}~dt\end{align}$$

therefore,

$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^a (x) \sin (a x) \ dx=\frac1{2^{a}}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac1{2m+1}\binom{a}{2m+1}}$$

Numerically verified by Wolfram as below,

[image]

---

**Byproduct**

For eq.(1), if we take real part,

$$\Re K=\frac{\pi}{2^{a+1}}$$

we get the byproduct

$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^a (x) \cos (a x) \ dx=\frac{\pi}{2^{a+1}}}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. $+1$. Can you please simplify the sum a bit.

Comment: I use Wolfram to take the sum, but it only gives hypergeometric functions, so I suspect it can be further simplified, since $a$ is not an integer. Wolfram gives $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac1{2m+1}\binom{a}{2m+1}=a\cdot\text{HypergeometricPFQ}\left[\{\frac12, \frac{1-a}2, 1 -\frac a2\}, \{\frac32, \frac32\}, 1\right]$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was expecting some simpler function like Gamma for instance see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456899/integrating-int-0-pi-2-cosax-cosbx-dx

Comment: Note that they are very different, because the post you linked is an even function, but your OP is odd function. This is the intrinsic difference. For odd function, we can't use symmetry to mirror it to the symmetric intervals, hence usually odd functions are harder and the result is more nasty than even functions. An good comparison is $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}dx~~~\text{vs}~~~\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{1+x^2}dx$$

Comment: Ok thanks. But still see if you could simplify the sum. I will wait for your edit.

Comment: I add the byproduct for the even function as you linked. For this OP, you can express the integral as incomplete beta function, but I think the summation form is better than incomplete beta function.

Comment: Ok thank you a lot

Comment: What made you choose all the arguments to be in the interval $(-\pi, \pi]$? If the two branch cuts lie on the imaginary axis where one goes upward and one goes downward, shouldn't $-\pi/2 < \text{arg}(z+i) \leq 3\pi/2$ and $-3\pi/2 \leq \text{arg}(z-i) < \pi/2$?

Comment: The choice of argument angle is arbitrary, I did this way since I want the combined argument angle for function $f$ on $C_3$ and $C_5$ to be zero. @Accelerator

Comment: @MathFail I wonder if we can get the hypergeometric representation directly from the integral itself and using the Euler integral formula for the hypergeometrics after the transformation $\cos(x)=t$. I tried this myself but didn't make much progress.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you would write the summands in terms of Gamma function.

Comment: It is NOT every integral finally goes to gamma function. Why do you think this integral will give gamma function? @Max

Comment: @Mathfail I am telling the SUMMAND not the sum. Sorry to confuse you.

Comment: @Max The result can be written as $$\frac1{a+1}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2m+1)B(2m+2,a-2m)}$$ Do you mean this? where $B$ is beta function.

Comment: Thanks. But I think you missed $2^{-a}$?

Comment: @Max Dude... don't you think it's rude to keep asking the answerer to rewrite their answer? If the final answer can be written as a Gamma function, then awesome, but you never seemed to ask for that in your original post.

Comment: Yes, I mean the summand part. You put that extra factor $2^{-a}$ for the complete result. @Max

Comment: One last question. Is the Beta function well defined here? Because in$B(2m+2,a-2m)$ for $a\geq 0$ and $m\geq1$, $a-2m$ can be negative?

Comment: You need to learn analytical continuation to answer this.

Comment: Your question doesn't hold at all. In your own work of your OP, you applied beta function, gamma function, and Euler's reflection formula, especially you used the $\Gamma(-a)$. Note that here the component is negative inside the Gamma function. If you never know how is the function well defined there, why can you apply those formulas in your own work? I agree with "Accelerator" that you should stop to keep asking these inconsistent questions. You can take any textbook for complex analysis and learn these basic concepts. @Max

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\left.\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{a}\pars{x}\sin\pars{ax}
\,\dd x\right\vert_{a\ >\ 0}} =
\Im\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{a}\pars{x}\expo{\ic ax}\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
\left.\Im\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ \pi/2}\pars{z + 1/z \over 2}^{a}z^{a}\,
{\dd z \over \ic z}\right\vert_{z\ \equiv\ \exp\pars{\ic x}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\left.-\,{1 \over 2^{a}}\,\Re\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ \pi/2}
{\pars{1 + z^{2}}^{a} \over z}
\dd z\right\vert_{z\ \equiv\ \exp\pars{\ic x}}
\end{align}
I'll "close" the integration along a quarter circle in the complex plane first quadrant $\pars{~\mbox{with an indent around}\ \ds{z = 0}~}$. Namely,
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\left.\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{a}\pars{x}\sin\pars{ax}
\,\dd x\right\vert_{a\ >\ 0}}
\\[5mm] \sr{{\rm as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim} & \
{1 \over 2^{a}}\,\Re\int_{1}^{\epsilon}
{\pars{1 - y^{2}}^{a} \over \ic y}\ic\dd y +
{1 \over 2^{a}}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}
{\pars{1 + x^{2}}^{a} \over x}\dd x
\\[5mm] \sr{{\rm as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\LARGE\to} & \
{1 \over 2^{a}}\int_{0}^{1}
{\pars{1 + x^{2}}^{a} - \pars{1 - x^{2}}^{a} \over x}\dd x \\[5mm] \sr{x^{2}\ \mapsto\ x}{=} & \
{1 \over 2^{a + 1}}\int_{0}^{1}
{\pars{1 + x}^{a} - \pars{1 - x}^{a} \over x}\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
\bbx{\color{#44f}{{1 \over 2^{a}}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{a \choose 2n + 1}{1 \over 2n + 1}}} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: How do you choose the branch cut? $(1+z^2)^a$ may give extra phase factor for different choices of branches.

Comment: @GGplay The principal branch-cut, as usual.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do we define $a \choose 2n + 1$ where $a\geq 0$ is a real number.

Comment: There are three branch points, how do you choose the cut for each of them? You haven't drawn the cut line yet, how can you say you choose the principle branch? @FelixMarin

Comment: In your own work of your OP, you applied beta function, gamma function, and Euler's reflection formula, especially you used the $\Gamma(-a)$ and $\Gamma(1-a)$, where $a$ is real positive number. If you don't know how are they defined, why can you applied them in your own work? Since they are all related to the binomial coefficients. @Max